# Parse backslash-delimited hierarchy path into separate columns

Tags: python, python-2.x, jython

I have rows in a database table with a `hierarchypath` column. The values in the column are hierarchy paths with up to four levels:

```
HIERARCHYPATH 
---------------------------------------------------
FACILITIES \ FIREHALL \ PLUMBING
FACILITIES \ PARK
ROADS \ GRASS/TURF BLVD MAINTENANCE
ROADS \ SIDEWALKS \ REPLACEMENT
FACILITIES \ PARKING - MAIN ST
RECREATION \ BANDSHELL \ PROPERTY \ BUILDING-GENERAL
FACILITIES
```

I've written a Jython 2.7 [automation script](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMAMS/com.ibm.mbs.doc/autoscript/c_automation_scripts.html) that parses the levels at the `\` delimiter and inserts the values into individual level columns:

- CLASSL1
- CLASSL2
- CLASSL3
- CLASSL4

```
#Example: 
s = "FACILITIES \ FIREHALL \ PLUMBING"

col_prefix = "CLASSL"

#Note: The term "mbo" is an IBM Maximo concept. 
#It can be thought of as the currently selected record in the application.

for i in range(0, 4):
    try:
        mbo.setValue(col_prefix + str(i+1), s.split(' \\ ')[i])
    except:
        #Null-out any existing values that were not overriden
        mbo.setValueNull(col_prefix + str(i+1))


HIERARCHYPATH                       CLASSL1       CLASSL2       CLASSL3      CLASSL4
--------------------------------    ----------    ----------    ----------   ----------- 
FACILITIES \ FIREHALL \ PLUMBING    FACILITIES    FIREHALL      PLUMBING     null
```

---

I'm relatively new to coding. How can the script be improved?

Comment: Why Jython? It's pretty old and unsupported.

Comment: @Reinderien Unfortunately, I don't have a choice. Jython is the standard scripting language for IBM Maximo. It's the only viable way to interact with the Java classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Normalization

A fully-normalized schema would not have four path component columns in a table; it would have one table with a string column for the path component, and a foreign key to its parent (and/or child), conceptually similar to a linked list. Advantages to this approach would be support for an arbitrarily long path. Disadvantage is likely decreased performance, though the scale of your problem is not clear.

Otherwise, I find it odd that you're parsing a path, and storing the result of the parse back into the database alongside the original data. This is a fast-enough operation that surely any advantage to caching parse results is outweighed by the disadvantage of increased storage and fetch time.

The only solid justification I can think of for such a thing is when (1) you know that certain interesting strings exist in fixed locations in the path, and (2) you need very fast, indexed querying on them, and (3) such querying is too slow when doing the usual pattern-matching approach on the original path.

### Iteration

Don't use `range` for your loop; use `enumerate`. Also use a raw string due to your backslash.

```
for i, part in enumerate(s.split(r' \ '), 1):
```

### Bare `except`

Generally this is a bad idea. At the least, catch `Exception` instead, or more preferably the actual exception type you expect to see. If it's only an index error because you're trying to index into a split that has fewer than four components, just avoid that situation altogether:

```
parts = s.split(r' \ ')
for i, part in enumerate(parts, 1):
    mbo.setValue(col_prefix + str(i), part)
for i in range(len(parts)+1, 5):
    mbo.setValueNull(col_prefix + str(i))
```